# Clarification on Key exchange approaches in TLS/SSL

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, tls

When RSA is used for key exchange in SSL, the client basically encrypts some random data using the server's public key and and sends it to the server. This data is then used to compute the shared key which is used for symmetric encryption.

When Diffie-Helman (DH) is used on the other hand, -- are the DH public values exchanged unecnrypted? I ask this because while the client can use the server's public key to encrypt DH values to be sent to the client, the server has no such key to encrypt data being sent to the client (since typically the client has no public keys of its own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are the DH public values exchanged unencrypted?

Yes, that are.  After all, they are "public values"; there's no weakness in exposing them in the clear.

Now, we do have to be careful that they aren't modified in transit (if they can be, then someone can perform a Man-in-the-Middle attack).  We do that by having the server sign its key share (using the private key of its certificate).

Comment: what about the DH values being sent by the client? The client has no way to sign them since it has no private key of its own typically. Does this mean the client encrypts is DH values (using server public key) while the server just signs its DH values?

Comment: @Minaj the client (usually) is not authenticated to the server and thus can't authenticate his shares in any way. The server just needs to trust that the client will detect an attacker if there's one.

Comment: No, the client sends its DH values in the clear.  Now, in the client direction, what's actually signed (if the client has a certificate) is not the DH values, but instead the master secret (which serves the same purpose)

Comment: @SEJPM: actually, the server is allowed to ask the client for a certificate.  That doesn't happen if you're using TLS to do web browsing (web servers don't really care who the client is); it does come up in other uses of TLS

Comment: @poncho, damn I meant to put a "usually" in there :/ fixed it tho :)

Comment: If the client sends its DH values in the clear -- they could be modified by the adversary--right? Since the client has already received the server's certificate, why no encrypt these DH values using the server's public key?

Comment: "they could be modified by the adversary--right?", well, they could be modified; however because the server's key share is signed, then the attacker must give that key share to the client (otherwise the client will detect that something's wrong); in that case, the adversary has no idea what keys the client has.  The adversary could pretend to be the client to the server (assuming no client certificate), however since the server would talk to anyone, that doesn't let him do anything he couldn't anyways.

Comment: @Minaj: as for why the protocol was done as it is, and not some other way, well, that's something for the SSL/TLS people to answer (as there are a lot of arbitrary decisions within TLS).  However, remember that not all certificate keys are encrypting keys; some certificates use ECDSA, and you can't encrypt with that; that's at least one reason the public DH values aren't encrypted.

Comment: Thanks; -- OK, I understand then that DH is preferred to RSA these days. And the reason for this is forward secrecy -- basically if someone gets access to the RSA private key, he can decrypt all communications and find the symmetric keys. But the same could be done with DH - right?

Comment: @Minaj: they could, if we kept the DH key around.  However, we don't; it's standard practice to clear out the DH private keys when we're done with them, and generate fresh ones as needed.  We could do the same with RSA, however a) the RSA cert chains aren't designed to make that easy, and b) generating fresh RSA keys is expensive

Comment: @Minaj What you are referring to is ephemeral (-ephemeral) Diffie-Hellman, denoted DHE or ECDHE in the cipher suites. Ephemeral key pairs can be destroyed after the pre-master key is established. You'd still need ECDSA, RSA for authentication. So it's not that DH is chosen *over* RSA; RSA certificates are still the main way of establishing authentication. And yes, especially in M2M connections (web-services) client authentication is commonly used.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I was referring to the stage after the server's RSA certificate has already been presented to the client. Would we still need RSA after this stage if we opt to use DH for key exchange?

Comment: Of course, the certificate is useless without RSA private key operation. Anybody can serve up a public certificate....

Comment: @Minaj+ even without client cert, TLS handshake including (EC)DHE kx is protected by Finished; see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work#20847 and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61535/what-stops-an-attacker-from-tampering-with-data-sent-during-the-ssl-tls-handshak and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71979/how-well-is-the-ssl-tls-handshake-protected-against-modifications . ...

Comment: ... This only fails if kx is broken *realtime*; see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89834/does-tls-fallback-scsv-provide-blanket-protection-against-downgrade-attacks and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115284/how-can-an-attacker-downgrade-modify-the-cipher-suites-when-they-are-maced